# Subresource requests using legacy protocols (like `ftp:`) are are blocked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been using below to browse files from ftp in google chrome, however, since couple of days, I am getting an error.

HTML code

```
<iframe src="ftp://IPAddress/Archive/Sample.pdf" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Error

> [Deprecation] Subresource requests using legacy protocols (like
>   `ftp:`) are are blocked. Please deliver web-accessible resources over
>   modern protocols like HTTPS. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5709390967472128 for details.

I have allowed anonymous access to ftp server, however, I think the update in google chrome caused this which the latest version of chrome doesn't allow such browsing.
Is there any work around?

Thank you

Comment: Hi. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: yeah, for my case, I configured it in IIS and access it using http instead of FTP; replace ftp with http, would work if you configure it in IIS.